# Python for loop over list with directories does not find every value

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of directories. I try just to keep those, which are named by number and not have some string name, e.g. "lastStableBuild". The following code removes every non-digit named directory except from "lastUnsuccessfulBuild".

```
for dir in listdir:
    print(dir, " ", end="")
    if not dir.isdigit():
        listdir.remove(dir)
```

While debugging I tried to print the whole list. There are several directories with "string names" listed, but not "lastUnsuccessfulBuild". Then I printed the whole list again, and now it was listed, and the other were removed. After executing the removal code again "lastUnsuccessfulBuild" was removed, too. I am really irritated.
This is the complete code:

```
listdir = os.listdir(rootdir)

for dir in listdir:
    print(dir, " ", end="")
    if not dir.isdigit():
        listdir.remove(dir)
print("")
print("________________After first removal_____________________________")

for dir in listdir:
    print(dir, " ", end="")

for dir in listdir:
    if not dir.isdigit():
        listdir.remove(dir)

print("")
print("________________After second removal_____________________________")
for dir in listdir:
    print(dir, " ", end="")
```

Which produces the following output:

```
> python listdir.py 
> 778  761  794  792  885  877  811  873  871  679 
> 726  771  837  691  783  751  813  780  852  723  721  801  826 
> 784  757  846  812  782  724  855  804  847  831  874  718  741  703 
> 789  756  688  825  824  748  875  697  676  798  747  705  736  765 
> 858  717  745  863  876  823  865  704  719  732  800  880  767  759 
> 842  815  753  779  680  833  752  734  716  696  851  834  682  708 
> 844  758  772  884  828  737  795  754  829  797  827  lastStableBuild
> 850  714  886  774  887  762  883  860  707  687  739  861  805  722 
> 763  859  845  817  822  864  821  749  699  746  802  711  857  867 
> 740  684  698  692  760  832  693  830  839  806  750  738  728  678 
> 818  710  727  701  888  849  729  843  841  744  764  814  872  766 
> 808  712  854  695  810  881  731  862  878  713  816  848  720  777 
> 700  lastUnstableBuild  775  769  742  791  866  694  725  796  770 
> 773  879  685  787  809  legacyIds  690  856  799  838  768  730  803 
> 793  677  686  683  807  743  lastFailedBuild  702  870  735  715  820
> lastSuccessfulBuild  835  836  785  733  776  706  786  781  788  709 
> 790  868  689  882  869  840  755 
> ________________After first removal_____________________________ 
> 778  761  794  792  885  877  811  873  871  679  726  771  837  691  783 
> 751  813  780  852  723  721  801  826  784  757  846  812  782  724 
> 855  804  847  831  874  718  741  703  789  756  688  825  824  748 
> 875  697  676  798  747  705  736  765  858  717  745  863  876  823 
> 865  704  719  732  800  880  767  759  842  815  753  779  680  833 
> 752  734  716  696  851  834  682  708  844  758  772  884  828  737 
> 795  754  829  797  827  675  850  714  886  774  887  762  883  860 
> 707  687  739  861  805  722  763  859  845  817  822  864  821  749 
> 699  746  802  711  857  867  740  684  698  692  760  832  693  830 
> 839  806  750  738  728  678  818  710  727  701  888  849  729  843 
> 841  744  764  814  872  766  808  712  854  695  810  881  731  862 
> 878  713  816  848  720  777  700  819  775  769  742  791  866  694 
> 725  796  770  773  879  685  787  809  681  690  856  799  838  768 
> 730  803  793  677  686  683  807  743  853  702  870  735  715  820 
> lastUnsuccessfulBuild  835  836  785  733  776  706  786  781  788 
> 709  790  868  689  882  869  840  755 
> ________________After second removal_____________________________ 
> 778  761  794  792  885  877  811  873  871  679  726  771  837  691  783 
> 751  813  780  852  723  721  801  826  784  757  846  812  782  724 
> 855  804  847  831  874  718  741  703  789  756  688  825  824  748 
> 875  697  676  798  747  705  736  765  858  717  745  863  876  823 
> 865  704  719  732  800  880  767  759  842  815  753  779  680  833 
> 752  734  716  696  851  834  682  708  844  758  772  884  828  737 
> 795  754  829  797  827  675  850  714  886  774  887  762  883  860 
> 707  687  739  861  805  722  763  859  845  817  822  864  821  749 
> 699  746  802  711  857  867  740  684  698  692  760  832  693  830 
> 839  806  750  738  728  678  818  710  727  701  888  849  729  843 
> 841  744  764  814  872  766  808  712  854  695  810  881  731  862 
> 878  713  816  848  720  777  700  819  775  769  742  791  866  694 
> 725  796  770  773  879  685  787  809  681  690  856  799  838  768 
> 730  803  793  677  686  683  807  743  853  702  870  735  715  820 
> 835  836  785  733  776  706  786  781  788  709  790  868  689  882 
> 869  840  755
```

The only thing, which comes to my mind, is that the for loop has a maximum of iterations, but I could not found anything about it.

What is the explanation of this behavior? And is there a better solution to get just the directories with "number names". (I can't determine the number of directories.)

Comment: There is a million duplicates for this : don't remove from a list while you iterate on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [don't change a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python).

Use list comprehension:

```
listdir = [dir for dir in listdir if dir.isdigit()]
```